# Facing problem with longtable while resizing textwidth

Tags: longtable

I have very large set of lengthy math equations, I have typed these equations in table so as to save space in original manuscript. Since I can not avoid writing these equation in my manuscript neither I can overload my manuscript with these beast equations, so I decided to resize text width so as to accommodate table within margin. In order to automatically shift portion of table to next page I tried using "longtable" command which work as desired but without " \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{.....}"   command.

How can I use longtable command along with "\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{.....}" ?? I have taken following code for example sake

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%for cursive font
\begin{document}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
 \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 \hline\hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline\hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline    
  \end{tabular}}\captionof{table}{How to shift long table along with resizebox.}\label{table3}
       \end{flushleft}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Simple: you cannot apply `\resizebox` to a `longtable`.

Comment: applying scaling to tables is always dubious so really it;s a good feature of longtable that it doesn't work at all. Just put `\small` or `\tiny` or whatever size you need before th e table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example fitted within the line so there was no need to change the size at all, so to make a real example I added an inch to the margin settings in the `geometry` options so the original table didn't fit, I then changed font size and the tabcol sep so it fitted in the narrow page.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.75in,right=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%for cursive font
\begin{document}
\begin{tiny}\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% was 6
 \begin{longtable}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 \hline\hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline\hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
 \hline    
  \caption{How to shift long table along with resizebox.\label{longtable}}
\end{longtable}
\end{tiny}
      \end{document}
```