# Resizing text inside longtable environment without resizing the caption

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, fontsize, booktabs

In my document there are several tables, of varying length, that added up take a lot of space. Therefore, I decided to reduce the size of the text in each table by using the `\small` command before the start of the `tabular` environment (inside the `table` environment) and after the `\caption` command, as shown in the first snippet of code.

**Standard table:**

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Standard table example.}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \small
        \begin{tabular}{lllr}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Book}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape{Timespan}} & \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Pages}} \\
        \cmidrule{2-3}
        & \slshape{Start} & \slshape{End} & \\
        \midrule
        001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
        002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
        003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
        004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
        005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:st_example}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

However, the same solution doesn't appear to be possible within the `longtable` environment, like for example in the following table.

**Table using `longtable` environment**

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtable}{lllr}
    \caption{Longtable example.} \\
    \label{tab:lt_example} \\
    
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Book}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape{Timespan}} & \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Pages}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \slshape{Start} & \slshape{End} & \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{{\tablename\thetable{}\itshape ... continues from the previous page}} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Book}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape{Timespan}} & \multirow{2}{4em}{\slshape{Pages}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \slshape{Start} & \slshape{End} & \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\itshape continues on the next page ...} \\
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & October 1884 & March 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & March 1896 & January 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & January 1901 & July 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & July 1911 & April 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & April 1923 & December 1947 & 526 \\
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I searched various suggestions online, but none of them was fitting to my case. The main problem is that I'm unable to scale the font without scaling also the caption of the table.

In 2016 the author of the `longtable` package in response to another user, wrote:

> applying scaling to tables is always dubious so really it;s a good feature of longtable that it doesn't work at all. Just put \small or \tiny or whatever size you need before th e table. –
> David Carlisle
> May 18, 2016
> [link to the thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310249/facing-problem-with-longtable-while-resizing-textwidth)

But by putting the resizing commands before the environment the caption is inevitably altered.

Is someone capable of reaching the same result shown in the first table also in the second? (possibly in a robust way)

Thanks in advance.

*PS. Probably the style of my tables can be improved, any suggestion is well accepted! thx!.*

Comment: Changing the font size is not the same as scaling, so go ahead.  You may need to use something like `\caption{\normalsize...}`, but try it without first.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Off-topic: `\slshape` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take a brace-delimited argument. Either write `\textsl{Start}` or `{\slshape Start}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnKormylo has already suggested in a comment, you can counteract the effect of `\small` on the contents of the caption by issuing a suitably-placed `\normalsize` directive. To implement this idea, I suggest you (a) load the `caption` package in the preamble, (b) issue the instructions

```
\begingroup
\small % or '\tiny', or whatever
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
```

immediately before `\begin{longtable}`, and (c) issue the instruction

```
\endgroup
```

immediately after `\end{longtable}`. That way, the scope of the `\small` and `\captionsetup{font=normalsize}` directives is limited to the `longtable` in question.

Do also note that `\slshape` is a switch -- similar to `\itshape`, `\bfseries`, and `\small` -- and hence does *not* take a brace-delimited argument. Write either `{\slshape Hello World}` or `\textsl{Hello World}`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}  % for \captionsetup directive
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next two instructions
\small
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}

\begin{longtable}{@{} lrrc @{}}
    \caption{Longtable example.} 
    \label{tab:lt_example} \\
    
    \toprule
    \slshape Book 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape Timespan}
    & \slshape pp. \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\slshape Start}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\slshape End} & \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\tablename~\thetable,  continued} \\[0.75ex]
    \toprule
    \slshape Book 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape Timespan} 
    & \slshape pp. \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\slshape Start}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\slshape End} & \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\itshape continues on next page} \\
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
    001 & Oct 1884 & Mar 1896 & 530 \\
    002 & Mar 1896 & Jan 1901 & 489 \\
    003 & Jan 1901 & Jul 1911 & 501 \\
    004 & Jul 1911 & Apr 1923 & 475 \\
    005 & Apr 1923 & Dec 1947 & 526 \\
\end{longtable}

\endgroup % matches the earlier \begingroup statement

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly, with your solution, the first (automatic) part of the caption (namely “Table 1:”) is also reduced in size along with the table text. This becomes obvious when instead of typing `\small` you use `\tiny`. This way the result is quite unpleasant. (thx for the formatting help btw)

Comment: Perfect, it now works as intended! My problem is solved, and my sorrow is relieved :D. Thanks for being nice.